# AWS lambda function to trigger a copy from source s3 to target s3 whenever a zip file is uploaded in source bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I created a event based triggering lambda function that copies a zip file from source s3 to target s3 whenever a zip file is loaded in source s3 bucket. Below is the lambda function in python:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import urllib
import boto3
print('Loading function')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
  key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object'] 
      ['key'].encode("utf8"))
  target_bucket =  'bucket name'
  copy_source = {'Bucket' :bucket , 'Key' : key}
  try:
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    print("CONTENT TYPE: " + response['ContentType'])
    return response['ContentType']
    print("copying from source to target")
    s3.copy_object(Bucket=target_bucket, 
            Key=key,CopySource=copy_source)
  except Exception as e: 
    print(e)
    print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they 
          exist and your bucket is in the same region as this 
            function.'.format(key, bucket))
    raise e
```

Below is the error message that I get by executing the code:

```
'Records': KeyError Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 13, in lambda_handler
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
KeyError: 'Records'
```

Any help to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you print the event & check if it indeed contains the *key* `Records`

Comment: let me check from my end on how to print the event i am pretty new to lambda

Comment: Your line `bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']` looks fine. There may be some other problem with the events in the lambda configuration.

Comment: how are you testing it? dropping a file on your s3 source bucket?

Comment: Thanks for your response josep valls even if i have just 3 lines in my code as below:def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
    print(event).                                         It always abends       "bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "errorMessage": "'Records'"

Comment: Thales Minussi yes i wanted to test like that but the code is not error free for me to test.

Comment: When i print the event i get START RequestId: 17d88ce9-eac3-472e-864d-72f695aa62de Version: $LATEST
{u'key3': u'value3', u'key2': u'value2', u'key1': u'value1'}